# kotlin: can't find a description of the ".()" syntax used in Compose library

Tags: kotlin, syntax

This might be a really stupid question but in the kotlin compose definitions, I see this:

```
@Composable
inline fun Column(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
...
}
```

I understand that the last **content** parameter is a composable function that returns nothing (`->Unit`) but I'm having a hard time understanding the **dot notation** in the `ColumnScope.()` fragment.

What is that about? I went through classes and functions documentation and also tried to google for kotlin ".()->" notation but I'm not finding anything. Is it literally a method named "()"? isn't that going to confuse the compiler? So I'm thinking it's not that. Happy to just be pointed at some docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [function type with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). Function types never have a name in their type--that wouldn't make sense.

The type `ColumnScope.() -> Unit` is similar to the type `(ColumnScope) -> Unit`, except that it doesn't have a ColumnScope parameter, it has a ColumnScope *receiver*.

The distinction between these two function types is only relevant when you pass a `lambda` as the function parameter. It allows you to treat the parameter as `this` instead of as a named parameter or implicit `it`.

In Compose, this makes it possible to in a lambda to call extension functions that are only relavent to the type of Composable you're working with.

For example, the children of a Column will want to use modifiers that are relevant to being within a Column, such as [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)). This is an extension function of Modifier that is defined in the ColumnScope interface. Therefore you can only call it if a ColumnScope is currently a receiver:

```
Column {
    Box(Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false))
}
```

If the function parameter was instead defined as `(ColumnScope) -> Unit`, you would have to take an extra step to bring the ColumnScope into scope as a receiver (aka `this`) using either `with` or `run` like this:

```
Column { columnScope ->
    Box(with(columnScope) { Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false) })
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, thanks! For some reason I have ZERO recollection of the page you linked to, and I could've sworn I read the section on functions and lambdas. :-(